# How do I call a method that has an abstract parameter?

Tags: java, abstract

I have a method in the `Map` class, `paint(Graphics g)`, that I need to call in my `main` method. The problem is, `Graphics` is abstract, so it can't be instantiated; I get this error: `Graphics is abstract; cannot be instantiated`. How would I call it then?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Drawing map
    Map m = new Map();
    Graphics g = new Graphics();
    m.paint(g);
}

public class Map
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawLine(284,46,305,46);
        g.drawLine(234,267,284,244);
        g.drawRect(10,10,64,64);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a class that extends `Graphics`. Make an instance of that new class and pass it to `paint`

Comment: What is in Map Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either create a sub class of Graphics, or use an existing sub class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an instance of a Graphics object, that is an instance of a class which extends graphics, and actually does the drawing you want. Probably the easiest way to do this is probably to use Swing. There are many tutorials on Swing, I would imagine a quick google search would quickly get you what you want.One way to do it : create a class extending `JComponent`, overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, which gives you the graphics object. Then create a `JFrame` (Ill call it frame),  and add an instance of your class to the `JFrame` with `frame.add()`. Then whenever the frame is repainted (you can force with `frame.repaint()`), your `paintComponent()` method will be called with a usable graphics object.